# How do I say I want one out of three FluentValidation rules to be applied?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, fluentvalidation, business-rules

I have a set of phone numbers, and not everybody has one of each of these numbers. How can I specify that any of the three being satisfied is good enough:

```
RuleFor(p => p.PhoneHome).Matches(Regexes.TenDigitsOnly).WithMessage("Phone numbers must have only ten digits.");
RuleFor(p => p.PhoneWork).Matches(Regexes.TenDigitsOnly).WithMessage("Phone numbers must have only ten digits.");
RuleFor(p => p.PhoneCell).Matches(Regexes.TenDigitsOnly).WithMessage("Phone numbers must have only ten digits.");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set up a custom validator that takes in the Model itself rather than just a property on it: http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Custom

Comment: Is it possible to use Fluent rules inside that custom validator> E.g. could I transfer my single phone number rules there, and just code the decision only invoking one?

Comment: Exactly - instead of `RuleFor` you would have `Custom(ValidatePhoneNumbers)` where `ValidatePhoneNumbers` would take the model as a parameter and perform the validation against the 3 numbers. Either return null if validation is successful or a `ValidationFailure` containing your custom message.

Answer (score 3):

You should use a business rules engine and stop hard coding logic in your main code. MS MVC's validation framework causes more problems in the long run than it solves. For example, this rule of yours can definitely change tomorrow. You'll have to rebuild and redeploy your entire app in order to change just one simple rule.

I'm posting this knowing that I'm going to get a lot of boos and downgrades from MVC die-hards.

Comment: Haha, no boos from me though, just an upvote. For me using Fluent Validation for MVC is a bit step toward using a proper rules engine; what with its incredible extensibility. A step toward a full rule engine is Fluent Validation rule methods that read rule data from an external source.

Comment: I'm interested in what you call a "business rules engine".  Do you have one you would recommend to use with say an mvc3/4 front end?

Comment: @GrayKing MS Workflow Foundation has a great BRE that can be used in any .NET environment (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/jj684582.aspx) If you have a BizTalk license, take a look at its BRE (http://www.microsoft.com/biztalk/en/us/default.aspx) If you need a solid web-based UI then take a look at WebRule (http://rule.codeeffects.com) Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You could set a property for a validation and apply it using the `Must` method.

```
RuleFor(p => p.PhoneHome)
    .Matches(Regexes.TenDigitsOnly).WithMessage("Phone numbers must have only ten digits.")
    .Must((person, phone) => ValidatePhones(person, phone))..WithMessage("Please add a phone number.");

RuleFor(p => p.PhoneWork)
    .Matches(Regexes.TenDigitsOnly).WithMessage("Phone numbers must have only ten digits.")
    .Must((person, phone) => ValidatePhones(person, phone))..WithMessage("Please add a phone number.");

RuleFor(p => p.PhoneCell)
    .Matches(Regexes.TenDigitsOnly).WithMessage("Phone numbers must have only ten digits.")
    .Must((person, phone) => ValidatePhones(person, phone))..WithMessage("Please add a phone number.");




private bool ValidatePhones(Person person, string phone) {
    return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(person.PhoneHome) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(person.PhoneWork) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(PhoneCell);
}
```

Take a look at Custom Validations:
http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Custom

Comment: I have no idea what your example is supposed to do. What do you mean by logic for all properties?

Comment: My only doubt here is that the rule is defined for `PhoneHome`. What effect would that have?